# API error when reloading the page, react js?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, undefined, fetch-api

I'm working on my first project and I get an error.

I fetch an API and call the first object to render on the page, it worked perfectly then I call a second object without reloading the page it also works but when I reload the page I get an error that the second object I'm calling is undefined.
Here's the code:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    async function getQuiz() {
        const res = await 
        fetch("https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=3&difficulty=easy&type=multiple")
        const data = await res.json()
        setQuiz(data.results)
         setQuizincorretanswer(data.results)}
    getQuiz()
  },[])

<QuizPage  
      questions = {quiz[0].question}
      answerone = {quizincorretanswer[0].incorrect_answers[1]}
/>
```

When I call the `incorrect_answers` alone without the `[1]` it works
but when I choose I specific array inside it like this  `incorrect_answers[1]` it crashes when reloads.

API link : https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=3&difficulty=easy&type=multiple

I tried to create a state for every incorrect answer
but didn't work either, tried also to many fetch methods but nothing worked.

Comment: What's error did you get?

Comment: i get the error undefined

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the  setIncorrectanser state to the question property of the result instead of the incorrect_answers array inside the useEffect.
See it in the yellow shaded area below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Succk.jpg)

Comment: i edited the post i was wrong about setQuizincorretanswer... can u read it again and tell me where's the problem

Answer (score 0):

Hi please [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html).check set value variable is not empty or null before you assign or render

Eg:Const value={result && result!==“” ?result.date : “ ”}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).